# Any way to set a default list of reviewers in Atlassian Crucible?

Tags: atlassian-crucible

We are using Atlassian Crucible for code reviews.  Every time I create a review, it shows me a list of about 40 reviewers from the entire project.  But only about 5 people in my group within the project need to review my code, so every time I have to manually remove about 35 people from the list of reviewers.

Is there any way to create a default list of reviewers for my code reviews?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a project and define default reviewers for a project. For ex you can have a default review group for Java projects and a different one fr DB projects

PS:- You would need admin privileges to do this

Comment: Where exactly do you define the default reviewers for a project?

Comment: Its in the project settings. The terminology and exact location depends on the crucible version. Which version are you using

Comment: Version 3.6.2.  I do not see any project settings.  The only settings I see are profile settings.

Comment: On the top crucible ribbon , you should see a menu item called "Projects". You can drill down from there.

Comment: I just found out only Crucible administrators can change the default reviewers.  Normal users like me can't do it.

Comment: And is there a way to set the default per repository ? I would like a setup where each repository has an individual fixed set of reviewers.